# Appropriate numerical scheme for eigen value problem

Tags: numerical-methods

I am looking for a numerical scheme which can easily handle the following eigen value problem
[image]

I already had the analytical results of this problem, now I want to know how to treat this problem numerically.

Any idea, then please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: And how is this related to *Mathematica* ? Any research you have done ? math.stackexchange ?

Comment: Just want to know, how to code it in Mathematica?

Comment: Do you already have an algorithm you wish to implement?

Comment: No idea mate how to write algorithm for this one?

Comment: Thx @NikolaDimitrov I have asked the same question on your suggested forum. I am sorry to bother you all. But still wondering to find a way to deal with it.